# SQL: LEFT OUTER JOIN not returning any rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have a query that is using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to merge 2 data sets. I know both data sets should return data because I ran the superquery and the subquery separately. For some reason, the query is returning zero results. Anyone know why?

Left data:

```
item        FG_lots
447845      E2211
```

Right data:

```
candy_lot_check    candy_item
L2211              835116
```

Intended result:

```
item        FG_lots   candy_lot_check    candy_item
447845      E2211     null               null
```

The result from my broken query (no results):

```
item        FG_lots   candy_lot_check    candy_item
```

The query:

```
--Initialization--
DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(30) = '447845'
DECLARE @Date datetime = '6/13/2016'
SET DATEFIRST 1;

DECLARE @client NVARCHAR(20)
SET @client = (SELECT i.Uf_ClientName FROM item AS i WHERE i.item = @Item)

DECLARE @count integer

--Query--
SET @count = (CASE 

                WHEN (@client = 'A' OR @client = 'B')
                    THEN 4 
                WHEN @client = 'C'
                    THEN 3
                WHEN @client = 'D' 
                    THEN 5
                ELSE
                    4
              END)


SELECT DISTINCT

    t.item,
    LEFT(t.lot,@count) AS FG_lots,
    (CASE
        WHEN candylot.candy_lots IS NULL
        THEN 'NO MATCH'
        ELSE candylot.candy_lots
    END) AS candy_lot_check,
    (CASE
        WHEN candylot.item IS NULL
        THEN 'NO MATCH'
        ELSE candylot.item
    END) AS candy_item


FROM

    ISW_LPTrans AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN

        (
            SELECT

                t.item,
                LEFT(t.lot,@count) AS candy_lots,
                t.ref_num AS job,
                t.ref_line_suf AS suffix

            FROM

                ISW_LPTrans AS t
                INNER JOIN item AS i on i.item = t.item

            WHERE

                i.product_code = 'RM-Candy' AND
                t.trans_date = @Date AND
                t.trans_type = 'I' AND
                t.ref_num IN

                    (
                        SELECT TOP 1

                            j.job

                        FROM

                            job AS j

                        WHERE

                            j.item = @Item AND
                            j.job_date = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date), @Date))

                        ORDER BY

                            j.job

                    ) 

                AND t.ref_line_suf IN

                    (

                        SELECT TOP 1

                            j.suffix

                        FROM

                            job AS j

                        WHERE

                            j.item = @Item AND
                            j.job_date = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date), @Date))       

                    ) 

            GROUP BY

                t.item,
                t.lot,
                t.ref_num,
                t.ref_line_suf

            ) AS candylot ON LEFT(t.lot, @count) = candylot.candy_lots 

WHERE

    t.ref_num = candylot.job AND
    t.ref_line_suf = candylot.suffix AND                    
    t.trans_type = 'F' AND
    t.item = @Item AND
    t.trans_date = @Date
```

Comment: Your `where` clause is turning the `left join` into an `inner join`.  All conditions on the second table should be in the `on` clauses.

Comment: beat me to it @GordonLinoff

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? :(

Comment: I did not downvote, but I'd say that was probably because you didn't try running the query part by part, without the `where` (the first thing you should do), to see why it wasn't returning any rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that was it. Feel free to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two 't' aliases, try altering it.

It seems you could rewrite it to make it more readable (joinwise, not indentwise), it could be that something's not right in the logic as well